# Help to modify URL from Table of Contents Web Part

Tags: 2010, web-part

I basically have a root site with multiple Sub sites beneath it. The Table of Contents web part will display the sub sites correctly, however I would like the URL to be modified. I want it to point to a specific page that all of the sub sites have, instead of the default Home page. Is there any easy way to do this?

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. figured it out myself. Just needed to add a content type to associate with the list which contained a link to the RDL report, and then in the content query web part add the reference, "URL;" which linked it directly to the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jQuery for this. Under `(document).ready` function you can use selectors to identify the `<a>` tag for each sub-site and then using string manipulation you can replace the default Home page by your own page.

[This](http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/customize-table-of-contents-remove-libraries-navigation-headers/) link may help you to start with.